# Merge Array of Objects by same key and restructure

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with merging an array of objects on the same key - "model" and restructuring it.

It should be also dynamic.

Original Array

```
var inputBl = [
    { model: 1, dim: 'd1', val: 'v1' },
    { model: 2, dim: 'd2', val: 'v2' },
    { model: 1, dim: 'd3', val: 'v3' },
    
]
```

First I got all unique model keys:

```
var keys = [];

inputBl.forEach(function(item) {
    keys.push(item.model);
});

let uniqueItems = [...new Set(keys)];
```

And then tried to restructure the object:

```
var obj = [];

uniqueItems.forEach(function(model) {
    inputBl.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.model == model) {
            obj.push({model: {dimensions: [item.dim]}})
        }
    });
});
```

But I get:

```
[ { model: [d1] }, { model: [d2] }, { model: [d3] }]
```

The ideal result (dynamic):

```
var ideal = [
    { 1: { dimensions: [d1, d3], values: [v1, v3] } },
    { 2: { dimensions: [d2], values: [v2] } },
];
```

Comment: Why is your ideal an array of heterogeneous objects? That's going to be more difficult to work with.

Comment: var output={};
inputBl.forEach(i=>{
    if(!output[i.model]) {
        output[i.model]={dimentions:[i.dim], values:[i.val]}
    }else{
        output[i.model]={dimentions:[...output[i.model].dimentions , i.dim], values:[...output[i.model].values ,i.val]}
    }
});